# JasperReports: How to put more than 1000 values in a list into $X() statement

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jasper-reports

I'm working on pdf report in web application in which i need to show report which can contain more than 1000 list

I have a main query in *JasperReports* (*iReport*) which looks like this

`<queryString><![CDATA[select SITE_NAME, SITE_OWNER, SITE_CONTACT_NAME, SITE_PHONE, SITE_FAX, SITE_MAIL from **SAMPLE_VIEW**  where $X{IN,site_id, siteIds}  group by SITE_NAME, SITE_OWNER, SITE_CONTACT_NAME, SITE_PHONE, SITE_FAX, SITE_MAIL by SITE_NAME]]>
</queryString>`

where $X{IN,site_id, siteIds}

siteIds - contains more than 1000 list of values.

site_id - column name of view

so problem i face is when the siteIds contains more than 1000 values i get following error

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : report name
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:229)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:758)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:623)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1160)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:802)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:746)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:247)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:573)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1891)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteDescribe(TTC7Protocol.java:830)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteQuery(OracleStatement.java:2391)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2672)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:589)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:527)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:222)
... 102 more
```

INFO - PDF Generator took 3667 ms.

The Exception **Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000**

i have solved it in Hibernate using

```
private static final int PARAMETER_LIMIT = 999;

public static Criterion buildInCriterion(String propertyName, List<?> collection) {
    Criterion criterion = null;
    List<?> subList;
    int listSize = collection.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i += PARAMETER_LIMIT) {
        if (listSize > i + PARAMETER_LIMIT) {
            subList = collection.subList(i, (i + PARAMETER_LIMIT));
        } else {
            subList = collection.subList(i, listSize);
        }
        if (criterion != null) {
            criterion = Restrictions.or(criterion, Restrictions.in(propertyName, subList));
        } else {
            criterion = Restrictions.in(propertyName, subList);
        }
    }
    return criterion;
}
```

Is there any solution that i can use in *JasperReports* for $X statement?

Comment: That's not a limitation of Jasper Reports. Oracle can't handle more than 1000 elements in an `IN` list. You will need to put the values into a (temporary?) table and then change the query to use a sub-select on that table. Something like `where site_id in (select ...) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you get is not Jasper-specific, but Oracle-specific; Oracle doesn't allow more than 1000 elements in an IN list.

If it's not possible to have Jasper automagically split the IN list into several sub-clauses, you could use one of these workarounds:

- write your IDs into a (temporary) table and replace your `$X{IN,site_id, siteIds}` with `WHERE site_id IN (SELECT site_id FROM <temporary_table_name> )`
- use a collection for your IDs and replace your `$X(IN,site_id,siteIds}` with `WHERE site_id IN (SELECT site_id FROM TABLE(<bindvariable_with_collection_holding_siteIDs>)` (this will only work if Jasper supports collections as bind variables)